# What to know about IIS?

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-6

I would like to know what kind of things in IIS are really important to you on a day to day basis? And what should I look into initially to get started?  Any articles/books/tutorials are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about getting into some Virtual Lab, such as:

http://virtuallabs.iis.net/

This link is full of resources also: http://learn.iis.net/

Answer (score 0):

The labs are a good place to start. Philosophically, the biggest thing to remember about IIS is it really is just a "phone switch" of sorts--it patches requests through to the appropriate handlers.

The other big thing to understand, IMHO, is the underlying windows security model. IIS rides on it and most folks who get into trouble are actually having trouble with windows security, not IIS. But the problems manifest themselves through IIS which can lead to some confusion.